# Create time variable based on binary variable using Stata

Tags: variables, stata

My dataset contains a year, ID, and binary value variable.

| ID | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 0 |
| 1 | 2001 | 0 |
| 1 | 2002 | 1 |
| 1 | 2003 | 1 |
| 1 | 2004 | 1 |
| 1 | 2005 | 1 |

Using Stata, I would like to create a new variable "YearValue" that takes the value of the variable "Year" when the variable value first turned 1.

| ID | Year | Value | YearValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 0 | 2002 |
| 1 | 2001 | 0 | 2002 |
| 1 | 2002 | 1 | 2002 |
| 1 | 2003 | 1 | 2002 |
| 1 | 2004 | 1 | 2002 |
| 1 | 2005 | 1 | 2002 |

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   egen wanted = min(cond(Value == 1, Year, .)), by(ID)
```

See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055 (especially Section 9) for this technique in context.